# How to draw a 3D hexagonal grid in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, data-visualization

What would be a good way to draw a figure such as the one shown in Figure 1 of the following paper: 
[here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5753.pdf)

It seems to be plotted with python, using matplotlib. But, maybe a tensorflow library or similar has been used, which I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try a [hexbin](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html) plot from matplotlib.

Comment: I also believe figure 3 is done with `hexbin` of matplotlib. However, for figure 1, I think it is drawn with `PowerPoint` due to its color scheme.

Comment: yeah, seems to be a PowerPoint plot. Thx for your help!